# request json validation in the flask

Tags: json, validation, flask

Is there some best practice how to validate json request in Flask?
There is interesting approach in the Flask restful extension but I don't need it in my app.
I just want to have something like this:

```
user_schema = {
    'username': email,
    'password': required,
    'age': required
}


@app.route('new_user/', methods=['POST'])
def new_user():
    validate_json(request.json, user_schema)
```

Comment: Might be worth looking at [WTForms-JSON](https://wtforms-json.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or similar.

Comment: What are you trying to validate? [Marshmallow](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) works great for serialization as well as validation.

Comment: I'm trying to validate JSON which came from the client. And I need to validate fields in this JSON.

Comment: You should use Marshmallow as @PatrickAllen mentioned. I have used webargs (https://webargs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) in a project wich is kind of built on top of marschmallow or rather using its validators. If you are building some kind of rest api you could give it a try.

Comment: thank you very much: @PatrickAllen and minato . I will look on both of them.

Answer (score 11):

Take a look at [cerberus](http://docs.python-cerberus.org)

Example usage:

```
>>> from cerberus import Validator
>>> schema = {'name': {'type': 'string', 'required': True}}
>>> v = Validator(schema)
>>> document = {'bla': 'john doe'}
>>> v.validate(document)
False
>>>
```